# Weird behaviour in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5, ios6

I'm developing an application using Xcode 4.6.1  for >iOS 5.0 version.

The application is simply displaying  questionnaires which were fetched from server side, saved in database and allow its users to fill it.

To show questions, i've a `UIScrollView` and i'm using it in **pagingEnabled mode**. I've three kinds of question choice type which are `checkbox`,`radio button` and `textfield`. For UI Controls, i've created `CheckBoxButton` and `RadioButton` class which are simply inherited from `UIButton`. I've set selection property by changing background image. So each page contains a question and `checkboxes | radio buttons` according to choice count. If choice count is 4, it's displaying 4 checkboxes.

If question and choices doesn't fit in the page, i'm creating a `UITableView` and i'm adding it to `UIScrollView` as a subview. Instead of using `UITableView`, i tried to use `UIScrollView` but it makes things worse. So,it's not really an option. To create `UITableViewCell`, i'm using this code.

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone ;
    }
        QuestionChoice *currentChoice =  [[[[_questionArray objectAtIndex:currentQuestionIndex] choices] allObjects ] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row -1 ];
        CheckBoxButton *checkBox = [[CheckBoxButton alloc] initWithXValue:20 yValue:0 tag:0];
        [cell addSubview:checkBox];
        UIFont *aeroSmall = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Aero" size:22.0f];
        NSString *choiceText = currentChoice.choiceText;
        CRTLabel *choiceLabel = [[CRTLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 0, 700, 44) andText:choiceText font:aeroSmall tag:0];
        [cell addSubview:choiceLabel];
```

I know that if a cell isn't present on the screen, it doesn't exist. My problem is with that. Let's say that i've checked fourth checkbox and scroll up, so that, fourth cell doesn't anymore display. When i scroll down, the fourth cell is going to be recreating by using above code. My problem is it's getting created with old status. It means that when i checked before scroll up, it's recreated in checked.

How is it possible ? What am i missing ? I didn't use any cache mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For efficiency's sake, iOS reuses table cells.  When your cell scrolls off the screen, it isn't deallocated.  Instead, it is thrown into the reuse queue.  When the cell reappears on the screen, the system grabs a cell from the reuse queue, if available, and hands it to you.  All of the subviews that you previously added to that cell are still there, so you need to clean up that cell and initialize it properly, otherwise you will see whatever was in that cell previously.

A UITableView is used to display a table.  It is not used to store any information.  In your case, you will want to know the state of a checkbox if someone checks it.  To get that state, you will want to add `target` and `action` to your checkbox so that you will get called if someone touches the checkbox and changes its state.

In your action method, you will need to store the value of the checkbox in a data structure that is a part of your view controller (not the table view).  You would also need to look at this data structure when recreating a cell that was off screen but has now reappeared.

Comment: If it isn't deallocated, let's say fourth cell in section 0 isn't displaying, why am i getting nil after cellForAtIndexPath method, is it normal ?

Comment: I'm not clear on the question in the comment.  What has a value of `nil` and when?

Comment: let's say, fourth cell is out of the screen, When i use self.tableView cellForAtIndexPath:indexPath, for section 0 and row 4, i get nil . But, you've said cell which is out of the screen doesn't get deallocated.

Comment: Do you mean `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?  That is called by the system to get the cell to display.  You shouldn't be calling that.  If you need to find out the state of the check box in your cell, then you should add `target` and `action` to it and store that information in your model or in your view controller.  Once a cell scrolls off the screen, for all intents and purposes, it is gone and any information with it.  In reality, the memory is still there and in the reuse queue as I mentioned above, but you shouldn't be trying to interact with it at that point.